# .htaccess redirect directly after domainname

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I want that if a user types in `www.example.com/article-title`, it gets the data from `www.example.com/index.php?title=article-title`. Right now it only works if a user types in `www.example.com/article/article-title`. I want to remove that `article/`.

This is what I have right now in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^article/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) index.php?title=$1 [NC,L]
```

If I remove `article/` from the last line in my .htaccess file, it doesn't work at all.

The `$1` should be `article-title`, but if I remove `article/`, `$1` becomes `index`.

Does anyone know how I can change the .htaccess in order to let users type in `www.example.com/article-title`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?title=$1 [NC]
```

tested [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) with

```
input: https://www.example.com/article-title
output: https://www.example.com/index.php?title=article-title
```

However i suppose this is actually what you really want, because by the looks of things you are not locking for a redirect, but something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

And then in the `index.php` file you have to "manipulate" the url requested